# Post Categories in default Keystone JS

Tags: content-management-system, keystonejs

I've been experimenting with Keystone CMS for the past week and I realised if you tagged your posts with categories that you've created in the post categories section, you'll get the following errors:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'
  at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/routes/views/blog.js:31:10)
  at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
  at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Promise.emit (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
  at Promise.fulfill (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
  at Promise.resolve (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:108:23)
  at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
  at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Promise.emit (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
  at Promise.fulfill (/Use rs/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
  at /Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1052:26
  at model.Document.init (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:250:11)
  at completeMany (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1050:12)
  at Object.cb (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1016:11)
  at Object._onImmediate (/Users/clippetmac/Sites/keystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that the async object that I've initialised does not have an "each" method.It turns out that I'm using an old async library that I've downloaded months ago. I installed the latest version of async and it worked like a charm.